# RSA Archer API Resource and Content Clarification

Tags: rest, security, soap, archer

I can access both the RSA REST and WSDL based APIs.  Their documents refer to content and resourses.  However, when logging into the actual tool I can access things like incident ticket and the like.

Incidents tickets will have INC-1234 which would be a string.  But the API takes integer values for either content or resource when searching by ID.

```
self.wsdl['search'].service.SearchRecordsByReport(
                sessionToken=self.token,
                reportIdOrGuid=14,
                pageNumber=1
)
```

If I don't provide an integer i get a 404 with a simple
"Message": "The request is invalid."  in the REST 
and something a little more complex if i pass a value like that in SOAP

So, Question 1.  is there an RSA resource that correlates/demystifies the relationships of calls in the API with the actual names of things I'm dealing with the in the UI.

Question 2. Is there a code library were someone has created/modified rsa incident tickets before out there?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about getting the record contentID you can get it two ways, in the GUI hover over your key field (the clickable link) and in the bottom left corner of archer it'll show something similar to "123456|100|17" where the first set is the contentID of that record.

If you're talking about getting a reportID (14 like you've shown above) you can do the same thing when you go to the master reports list, and it'll show in the bottom right corner of your browser.

If you want to do it all from code I usually piece it together like this:

1. Execute a search of a report; Get the field IDs from the report <FieldDefinition> (it's probably important to make sure your keyfield is included on the report GUI so you'll be able to identify which record you're dealing with); make another API call (probably REST since it really handles the metadata) to get the field name etc. (or you could make it all static and just hard-code the field names with the corresponding GUIDS)
2. Within the <Record> tag, you can snag the contentID attribute. Then take a step down and compare the field tag that matches your keyfield and you'll have the contentID of that record.
3. Make record updates, deletes, etc whatever you need to do.

If you're looking for a specific report ID, make a REST call to get all reports, and it'll return report names and IDs, and then go about your business making your other calls.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently came across similar situation where I have to search for a field value (e.g. "INC-1234") using Archer's API.

So, for your **Question 1**:
The method that I found convenient to my requirements is "ExecuteQuickSearchWithModuleIds" which can search for a value and provides all ContentIDs that have those values (given the ModuleId).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ExecuteQuickSearchWithModuleIds xmlns="http://archer-tech.com/webservices/">
      <sessionToken>ABC123ABC123ABC123ABC123ABC1</sessionToken>
      <moduleIds>123</moduleIds>
      <keywords>INC-1234</keywords>
      <pageNumber>9999999</pageNumber>
      <pageSize>9999999</pageSize>
    </ExecuteQuickSearchWithModuleIds>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And for your **Question 2**, I found a rich library for Python3 [Archer RSA](https://github.com/mwa21/rsa_archer).

Hope this helps someone who lands on this question.